# toggleClass not working on another element

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying this scenario but its not working. I want to toggle class on an element when another element is clicked.

Below is my html/css/jquery

html

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

css

```
.box1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}
.box2{
   height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

jquery

```
$('.box1').click(function(){
 $('.box2').toggleClass('blue'); 
});
```

liveweave can be viewed here. I already searched on internet and i think there is no error in my code but still i dont understand why it doesnt work

http://liveweave.com/zIfs3U

someone guide please

Answer (score 3):

Since `.box2` and `.blue` classes have the same precedence (they are both class names) you have to put `blue` after the `.box2` in order it to be higher and be applied:

```
.box2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

So summarizing: if CSS selectors have the same weight (like in case above), the one defined last gets applied.

Another option is to write CSS rule like this (preferred):

```
.box2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.box2.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

Read about ["CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), important information to know.

Comment: As I said in the answer since both classes have the same weight the one you define last gets applied.

Comment: You could also cover the use of `!important` (even though it should, really, never be used). Still: +1 for being a little ahead of my own answer, with pretty much the same answer. :)

Comment: i think i have problem understanding the precedence. Can you help me guide to any article that help me better understand this topic

Comment: @Amer The rules of precedence act for browsers to determine what CSS selector to use for element styles. Read this article and everything will come clear: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

**jQuery**

```
$('.box1').click(function (e) {
    $('.box2').toggleClass('blue');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.box1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ekdv5xu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.box1').on('click', function(){
  $('.box2').toggleClass('blue'); 
});
```